# How can I substantiate grammatically about Much and a lot of here?

Tags: grammar

Take a look at these two sentence:

A- I like a lot of milk in my coffee.
B- I like much milk in my coffee.

If B is not correct, is it only because we do not use much in affirmative sentences and mostly we use it in negative and question sentences? Or is there another grammatical reason behind it?

Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no grammatical reason. _Much_ can be, and used to be, used in that sense, but for some reason 'a lot of' is more idiomatic in that context nowadays.

Comment: You're right. "Much" generally (but certainly not always) occurs in non-affirmative contexts.

Comment: I suspect, but cannot prove, that the problem is the collision with *like* meaning akin to, as in "Like much milk in one's coffee, the day was full of excess." We can certainly say, "There was so *much milk* in my coffee that I was overjoyed." Which seems abundantly affirmative.